# All solutions of $f(x)f(-x)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, functional-equations

> What are all the solutions of the functional equation $$f(x)f(-x)=1\,?$$

This one is trivial: $$f(x)=e^{cx},$$
as it is implied (for example) by the fundamental property of exponentials, namely $e^a e^b=e^{a+b}$. But there is another solution:
$$f(x)=\frac{c+x}{c-x}.$$
Are there any more solutions? How can I be sure?

Comment: Great question! How did you find your second solution?

Comment: One more solution : $f(x) =(1+|x|)^x$ or in general : $f(x) =(1+g(x)) ^x $, where $g(x) $ is an even function such that $g(x) \ne - 1$ for any $x$

Comment: Actually I did not come up with the second solution myself. I plugged the functional equation to a calculator and it gave me the second solution.

Comment: You probably need to add some requirements otherwise literally any $f:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\to \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ can be extended to $\mathbb{R}$ by letting $f(x) =1/f(-x)$ for $x<0$ and $f(0)=1$.

Comment: This may be helpful, too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683492/fx-is-an-analytic-function-in-mathbbr-such-that-f-xfx-1-what-els

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Presumably, you want $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.  If you want to use a different domain or codomain, the answer is probably not going to change much.

You can simply pick any $h:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\to\mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ and $\epsilon\in\{-1,+1\}$.  Then, define the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$f(x):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
h(x)&\text{if }x>0\,,\\
\epsilon&\text{if }x=0\,,\\
\dfrac{1}{h(-x)}&\text{if }x<0\,.
\end{array}\right.$$
Then, $f$ satisfies the required functional equation.  Note that any such function $f$ takes the form above.

If you demand that $f$ is continuous, then $h$ has to be continuous and $\lim\limits_{t\to 0^+}\,h(t)=\epsilon$.  This is all you need.  It is a much more interesting problem to characterize all smooth or analytic functions $f$ that satisfy your functional equation.  It turns out that the solutions are $f(x)=\epsilon\,\exp\big(g(x)\big)$, where $\epsilon\in\{-1,+1\}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth or analytic, odd function.  If you want $f$ to be just $k$-time differentiable, then $g$ is $k$-time differentiable.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the most general solution: Let $g: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$ be any function such that $g(0)=\pm 1$  and define  $f(x)=g(x)$ if $x \geq 0$ and $f(x) =\frac  1 {g(-x)}$ if $x \leq 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Take any function that is odd, that means $g(-x)=-g(x)$.  For example $\sin x, x^3+2x$ and so on.  Then $\exp(g(x))$ works.

Comment: Also $\frac {f(x)+g(x)}{f(x)-g(x)}$ where $g$ is odd and $f$ is even.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Sir, also $ f(x) =(1+g(x)) ^x$ where $g(x) $ is an even function such that $g(x) \ne - 1$ for any $x$.

Comment: Very interesting. Does this capture all solutions of the functional equation?

Comment: @MrPink - Take a look at my comment above. You may find extra information :)

Comment: @MrPink No . All solutions are captured in my answer.

Comment: @MrPink No, $\exp(\dots)$ is positive everywhere while this is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

This is the case if and only if $x\mapsto\ln \lvert f(x)\rvert$ is an odd function, i.e. if and only if there are some odd function $g$ and some function $\theta:\Bbb R\to\{-1,1\}$ such that $f(x)=\theta(x)e^{g(x)}$

It is clear that the correspondence is bijective because $\theta=\frac f{\lvert f\rvert}$ and $g=\ln\lvert f\rvert$.

Answer (score 3):

Take any even function $h(x) $ and an odd function $g(x) $, then $f(x) =(h(x)) ^{g(x)} $ where $h(x) >0 $ for any $x\in \mathbb R$, does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

For ant function $f(x)$ that is a solution, $-f(x)$ is also a solution. So $f(x)=-1$ is such an example. Then, if you don't impose continuity requirements, you can have more examples. Also, piecewise defined function would work:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x, x>1\\1,-1\le x\le 1\\-1/x,x<-1\end{cases}$$